# JavaFX: How to enable/disable a particular cell in a row based on the value in other cell of the same row?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a javafx TableView. Few columns have custom cell factory set to display TextField, ComboBox, DatePicker etc.
When user selects a particular value in the combobox table column then the next cell on the same row should be disabled from editing.

Comment: Bindings should be your buddy here.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: @fabian The previous question contains multiple questions and it was unanswered. I thought it was not described properly and i asked this question.